# How to move VirtualBox all VMs to another PC at once?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

In my windows 8 I have VirtualBox installed and it has lot of VMs running. I have another PC which has virtualbox installed on it.I want to move all VMs from my old PC to new PC at once. How do I do that in easy way?

Comment: Great stuff.  What's your programming question?

Comment: Thanks for reply ghoti. I have edited the question. Please check and reply.

Comment: This isn't exactly a programming question.  You haven't provided example code that people can correct for you, you're just asking for instructions that are probably handled in existing documentation for the product you're using.  Perhaps your question would be better placed on http://serverfault.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Do a backup and restore would be an answer.
Be aware that virtualbox keeps track of the UUID of your virtual hard disk.

If you rephrase your question and tell the audience what you precisely want. Merely a copy and go on? Or just a move operation?

Having two PC's with the same VM's do have an impact on your home network if the VM's are connected to the internet.